# How do I make an armor stand chase the player?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to create an entity that chases you around the backrooms. I've tried using some basic teleport commands, but it's not doing what I want it to. I want the armor stand to teleport to you whenever it "sees" you. But I can't figure out how to teleport it based on its previous location preferably with 1 repeating command block. I'm on bedrock edition so tags won't work.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our [guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.